# Get Location Marker in Google Maps SDK for native iOS/ swift

Tags: swift

im working on an App for iOS where I embedded the new Google Map for native iOS. Everything works fine except one problem where I can´t find a propper solution for native IOS/ swift neither here nor at google (if there is one please show me and sorry for annoying you)

I need get location fro new position when change marker location in map

How can I do that?

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solve using this function :

```
func mapView(mapViewUIView: GMSMapView!, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    marker.position.latitude = coordinate.latitude
    marker.position.longitude = coordinate.longitude

    println(marker.position.latitude)
    let ULlocation = marker.position.latitude
    let ULlgocation = marker.position.longitude

}
```